# Add datetime rules to model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

In my CodeIgniter model one of the fields is a leasestart and a leaseend for setting the range of a property lease. I currently have something similar to the below. Whats the syntax for setting rules on a datetime? Or just date for that matter.

```
public $rules = array(
  'unitnum' => array(
    'field' => 'unitnum',
    'label' => 'UnitNum',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|numeric|xss_clean'
  ),
  'rent' => array(
    'field' => 'rent',
    'label' => 'Rent',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|numeric|greater_than[0]|xss_clean'
  ),
  'leasestart' => array(
    'field' => 'leasestart',
    'label' => 'LeaseStart',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|????|xss_clean'
  ),
  'leaseend' => array(
    'field' => 'leaseend',
    'label' => 'LeaseEnd',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|????|xss_clean'
  ),

);
```

Comment: you want to check start date not greater then end date, and end date no equal and lesser than start date am i right or not

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no date time rules for codeigniter. You'll have to use a callback.

EDIT: Also you also only need to specify the callback in either the lease end or lease start since it checks both values either way.

```
public $rules = array(
 'unitnum' => array(
    'field' => 'unitnum',
    'label' => 'UnitNum',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|numeric|xss_clean'
  ),
  'rent' => array(
    'field' => 'rent',
    'label' => 'Rent',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|numeric|greater_than[0]|xss_clean'
  ),
  'leasestart' => array(
    'field' => 'leasestart',
    'label' => 'LeaseStart',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|callback__check_lease|xss_clean'
  ),
  'leaseend' => array(
    'field' => 'leaseend',
    'label' => 'LeaseEnd',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
  ),

);
```

Your function could look like this, but keep in mind of your date formatting so you can use `strtotime()`.

```
function _check_lease($lease_start){
    $lease_start = strtotime($lease_start);
    $lease_end = strtotime($this->input->post('leasestart'));

    if($lease_start > $lease_end){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_lease', 'Invalid range, lease time cannot be greater than lease end.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i have all my rules stored in the model `unit_m`. Would teh callback also be stored there? Or would it be in the controller `unit` that calls `form_validation`?

Comment: It would be stored in stored in the controller where you call the form validation. The underscore at the front of the function like _check_lease means that it cannot be accessed through URL like a normal controller function such as check_lease.
Ex.

www.example.com/_check_lease - Won't work.
www.example.com/check_lease - Would work